# Is there a way to read grunt tasks via terminal?

Tags: gruntjs

I would like to get the registered Tasks from a gruntfile via terminal.

Example:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', ['clean', 'compass', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'imagemin', 'copy:test', 'ftp-deploy:test', 'clean']);
```

then on the terminal I would type something like

```
$> grunt --listtasks
```

Even better if I could register each task with a description like so:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', 'this task deploys to testserver',['clean', 'compass', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'imagemin', 'copy:test', 'ftp-deploy:test', 'clean']);
```

Then the output could be something like:

```
$> test: this task deploys to testserver (clean, compass, uglify, cssmin, imagemin, copy:test, ftp-deploy:test, clean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `grunt --help` to get a list of all registered tasks. This shows the command and the task description. Example output:

```
$ grunt --help
Grunt: The JavaScript Task Runner (v0.4.1)

Usage
 grunt [options] [task [task ...]]

Options
         --help, -h  Display this help text.
             --base  Specify an alternate base path. By default, all file paths
                     are relative to the Gruntfile. (grunt.file.setBase) *
         --no-color  Disable colored output.
        --gruntfile  Specify an alternate Gruntfile. By default, grunt looks in
                     the current or parent directories for the nearest
                     Gruntfile.js or Gruntfile.coffee file.
        --debug, -d  Enable debugging mode for tasks that support it.
            --stack  Print a stack trace when exiting with a warning or fatal
                     error.
        --force, -f  A way to force your way past warnings. Want a suggestion?
                     Don't use this option, fix your code.
            --tasks  Additional directory paths to scan for task and "extra"
                     files. (grunt.loadTasks) *
              --npm  Npm-installed grunt plugins to scan for task and "extra"
                     files. (grunt.loadNpmTasks) *
         --no-write  Disable writing files (dry run).
      --verbose, -v  Verbose mode. A lot more information output.
      --version, -V  Print the grunt version. Combine with --verbose for more
                     info.
       --completion  Output shell auto-completion rules. See the grunt-cli
                     documentation for more information.

Options marked with * have methods exposed via the grunt API and should instead
be specified inside the Gruntfile wherever possible.

Available tasks
            rosetta  Shared variables between JS and CSS. *
            asciify  Ascii awesomizer. A Grunt task for better banners and hot
                     logs. *
              clear  Clear your terminal window
              clean  Clean files and folders. *
             concat  Concatenate files. *
             jshint  Validate files with JSHint. *
               sass  Compile Sass to CSS *
              watch  Run predefined tasks whenever watched files change.
               csso  Minify CSS files with CSSO. *
         lintspaces  Checking spaces *
              newer  Run a task with only those source files that have been
                     modified since the last successful run.
          any-newer  Run a task with all source files if any have been modified
                     since the last successful run.
    newer-timestamp  Internal task.
             svgmin  Minify SVG *
 trimtrailingspaces  Removing the trailing spaces *
            webfont  Compile separate SVG files to webfont *

Tasks run in the order specified. Arguments may be passed to tasks that accept
them by using colons, like "lint:files". Tasks marked with * are "multi tasks"
and will iterate over all sub-targets if no argument is specified.

The list of available tasks may change based on tasks directories or grunt
plugins specified in the Gruntfile or via command-line options.

For more information, see http://gruntjs.com/
```

Comment: this is kind of it. maybe the description would be a good feature? Or maybe a seperate command to only display tasks?

Comment: I don't believe that there's anything out there already that offers a stripped back version of this output as you describe. This could be a potential plugin opportunity. :)

Comment: Because of the way Grunt works, the list of tasks is converted to a function when the task is registered, so it's not currently possible to show what the task aliases. However, I managed to get a separate command to list all your registered tasks working. You can check it out here: https://github.com/ben-eb/grunt-available-tasks

Answer (score 1):

Or have a look at [grunt-available-tasks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-available-tasks):

[image: example output]